# How to silence print messages while executing a code using trace library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace

I am tracing a code by using the [trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) library. While executing the other code, I am getting some print messages on the screen that there exist. How can I silence them?

```
def generate_sequential_function_calls(self):
    """generate sequential function calls
    for tracing source code and plotting sequence diagram.
    """
    # generating sequence diagram for a use-case
    _ = GenerateSequenceDiagram(
        self.driver_path, self.driver_name, self.source_code_path[0])
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
        self.driver_name, self.driver_path)
    global foo
    foo = self.foo
    foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
    tracer = Trace(countfuncs=1, countcallers=1, timing=1)
    tracer.run('foo.{}()'.format(self.driver_function))
    results = tracer.results()
    caller_functions = results.callers
    function_sequence = []  # consists of all functions called in sequence
    for caller, callee in caller_functions:
        _, caller_module, caller_function = caller
        _, callee_module, callee_function = callee
        if caller_module not in self.source_code_modules or callee_module not in self.source_code_modules:
            logging.debug(
                "Following modules are not in source code and thus to be ignored:")
            logging.debug(caller_module)
            continue
        function_sequence.append(
            [(caller_module, caller_function), (callee_module, callee_function)])
    logging.debug("Function sequence is: ")
    for sequence in function_sequence:
        logging.debug(sequence)
```

I tried setting the logging level on my own code but in vain.

The executed code has normal `print` statements, as shown [here](https://github.com/kebab-mai-haddi/python3-class-inheritance-dependency-example/blob/master/car.py#L33).

This is what I get on my screen:

```
Inside main_2 func
False
True
The dataframe is:
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
INFO:root:docker cp gruml://home/ubuntu/generate_uml/Use_Case_test_cliDependency_2.xlsx .
```

The unwanted lines are all but the last one.

Answer (score 0):

`logging` library uses `STDERR` to do it's logging, while `print()` uses `STDIN`.

That said, you can redirect the outputs to get only what is printed to `STDERR` (assuming that this other garbage-prints are made to STDIN).

In linux you would do something like:

```sh
python my_program.py >/dev/null
```

This is redirecting the outputs of *file descriptor* 1 to /dev/null (a black hole of I/O). Therefore, the contents being printed to file descriptor 2 (STDERR) should still be printed.

If you are using another OS you should look for something on this behalf.